# How to prevent a child record from being deleted

Tags: sql-server

When delete a master record a cascade trigger will get fired and delete the records in the child tables.
And I cannot delete a record manually from the table as it got a foreign key relation with child table.

But how can I prevent the child record from being deleted manually from the table. Currently I am able to delete the child record manually and on page loads as the child record is missing and page load fails.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure who or what would manually delete records from this table, but I would lean towards using **[DENY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173724(v=sql.110).aspx)** permissions with this requirement, and ensure all roles on that database have no `delete` permissions on that table.

**Sample script:**

```
USE [YOUR_DB]
GO
DENY DELETE ON [dbo].[YOUR_TABLE] TO [DOMAIN\user]
GO
```

Replace `[dbo]` with relevant schema name and replace `[DOMAIN\user]` with the relevant user.

Comment: Thanks Tanner. But I needs to delete the records from the child table when delete the appropriate records in the master table. ie, when delete a record in the master table a cascade delete trigger will get fired to delete the records from the child table. In this case if we apply Deny delete the cascade delete will get failed or not.

Comment: who exactly are you worried about "manually" deleting records? your application or domain users?

Comment: @user1921730 so the application or your sys admin users have permission to delete records as required, but any other users have this DENY permissions. So any random users you're worried about would not be able to delete records from the child table. If there's more to this problem, please update your question with scenarios and more details to clarify things.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit unclear as to why you'd want to have something like this done.  You simply don't allow for the deletion of child records on the UI aside from your cascade delete - just don't give the user the option.

If you're worried about some random DBA going in to your database and writing:

```
delete from childTable where parentId = 5 -- or whatever
```

then i think you have more things to worry about... such as why people with production database write access are even thinking about manually writing and executing statements such as this on your prod database.

If you still *really* needed to do something like this.  You could potentially write a before delete trigger on all of your child tables to ensure that the parentId doesn't exist in the parent table prior to delete.  This would *likely* cause your cascade delete to fail (i would guess) so you would need to update your cascade delete functionality to disable the trigger before deletion, re-enabling the trigger after.  But this would not prevent your "random dba" from just doing something similar by disabling the trigger, deleting a record, and re-enabling.

If you provide a little more information around the specific scenarios of why a child record would "manually" be deleted, might be able to offer more.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The OP wants to only allow a child record to be deleted through the CASCADE delete, and prevent a delete on the child record alone.

Comment: The child record can be accidentally deleted by the administrator through management studio. If we disable the trigger the other users who simultaneuosly working will not be able to make use of the trigger.

Comment: the administrator could also accidentally drop all tables in your database through management studio.  It's a risk of giving dbo permissions to any person on your production database.  I'm not really sure what you're hoping to accomplish here without limiting user access to your database

Comment: the record can be deleted unless they are used in another table, i can maybe use : where id is not in (select parent_id from child_table) but i thought there is a better cleaner way